# bash, using awk command for printing lines characters if condition

Tags: bash, awk

Before starting to explain my issue I have to say that it's the first time I'm using bash and the awk command.

I have a file containing a lot of lines and I am interested in printing some of these lines if certain characters of the line satisfy a condition. I already have a simple method which is working but I intend to try with awk to see if it can be faster. The command I'm trying was inspired by a colleague at work but I don't fully understand it.

My file looks like :

```
@ 15247.479
1 23775U 96005A   18088.90328565 -.00000293 +00000-0 +00000-0 0 9992
2 23775 014.2616 019.1859 0018427 174.9850 255.8427 00.99889926081074
@ 15250.479
1 23775U 96005A   18088.35358271 -.00000295 +00000-0 +00000-0 0 9990
2 23775 014.2614 019.1913 0018425 174.9634 058.1812 00.99890136081067
```

The 4th field number refers to a date and I want to print the lines starting with 1 and 2 if the bold number if superior to *startDate* and inferior to *endDate*.

I am trying with :

```
< $file awk ' BEGIN {ok=0} 
    {date=substring($0,19,10) if ($date>='$firstTime' && $date<= '$lastTime' ) {print; ok=1} else ok=0;next} 
    {if (ok) print}'
```

This returns a syntax error but I fear it is not the only problem. I don't really understand what the *$0* in substring refers to.

Thanks everyone for the help !

Comment: One question.... is the date you are interested in always on the line immediately following the line matching `/^@/` -- it will change the answer a bit.

Comment: yes it's always on the line following the line with @, and if the condition matches I want to print both lines number 1 and number 2 (respectively starting by 1 and 2)

Comment: Ok, I thought it might... and even though you have accepted my current answer (thank you) I will add another solution in a bit to help you out that is in accordance with this new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the question about `$0`:

**Awk** is a language built for processing tables and has language features specific to both filtering and manipulating tabular data.  One language feature is automatic field splitting.

If you see a `$` in front of a variable or constant, it is referring to a "field."  When **awk** sees `$`*field_number* being used in a variable context, **awk** splits the current record buffer based upon what is in the FS variable and allows you to work on that just as you would any other variable -- just that the backing store for that variable is the record buffer.

`$0` is a special field referring to the whole of the record buffer.  There are some interesting notes in the **awk** documentation about the side effects on `$0` of assigning `$`*field_number* variables, `FS` and `OFS` that are worth an in depth read.

Here is my answer to your application:

(1) First, `LC_ALL` may help us for speed. I'm using `ll`/`ul` for lower and upper limits -- the reason for which will be apparent later.  Specifying them as variables outside the script helps our readability. It is good practice to properly quote shell variables.

(2) It is good practice to use `BEGIN { ... }`, as you did in your attempt, to formally initialize variables.  If using **gawk**, we can use `LINT = 1` to test things like this.

(3) `/^@/` is probably the simplest (and fastest) pattern for our reset.  We use `next` because we never want to apply the limits to this line and we never want to see this line in our output (even if `ll = ul = ""`).

(4) It is surprisingly easy to make a mistake on limits. Implement limits consistently one way, and our readers will thank us.  We remember to check corner cases where `ll` and/or `ul` are blank.  One corner case is where we have already triggered our limits and we are waiting for `/^@/` -- we don't want to rescan the limits again while ok.

(5) The default action of a pattern is to `print`.

(6) Remembering to quote our filename variable will save us someday when we inevitably encounter the stray `"$file"` with spaces in the name.

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v ll="$firstTime" -v ul="$lastTime" '                 # (1)
    BEGIN { ok = 0 }                                                # (2)
    /^@/  { ok = 0; next }                                          # (3)
    !ok   { ok = (ll == "" || ll <= $4) && (ul == "" || $4 <= ul) } # (4)
    ok    # <- print if ok                                          # (5)
' "$file"                                                           # (6)
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I tried your code but it returns nothing (I know that at some points conditions are met and therefore the code should return something). If $4 refers as I think to the 4th field then if may be the issue because there are several spaces between the third field of line 1 and the fourth field of line 1 (the lines starting by "1")

Comment: I mixed your solution with what I was trying and it worked ! However I have one question : how did you do for printing also the second line ? I was having issues trying this, I only succeed in printing first line when the condition on the date was verified.

Comment: The way my solution works is to print via “default action.”  **Awk**’s structure is always “pattern { action }”.  If we do not provide the ‘{ action }’, **awk** substitutes the default action, which is to print. So, on line (5), our pattern is the “ok.” I could have made this explicit saying “ok { print }”, but that just feels inelegant to **awk**ers, and I would have inevitably been “poo-poo’d.”  If the mashup of our solutions is right, both lines 1 and 2 should print, but... in any case, there is no reason that we cannot insert a print statement anywhere else in any action.

Comment: And, by default, **awk** is “greedy” for spaces in the field separator; so, $4 should be right unless in the mashup you have explicitly set the -F parameter or the FS variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `;` between the variable assignment and `if`. And instead of concatenating shell variables, assign them to `awk` variables. There's no need to initialize `ok=0`, uninitialized variables are automatically treated as falsey. And if you want to access a field of the input, use `$n` where `n` is the field number, rather than `substr()`.

You need to set `ok=0` when you get to the next line beginning with `@`, otherwise you'll just keep printing the rest of the file.

```
awk -v firstTime="$firstTime" -v lastTime="$lastTime" '
    NF > 3 && $4 > firstTime && $4 <= lastTime { print; ok=1 }
    $1 == "@" { ok = 0 }
    ok { print }' "$file"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion and the bash command is working. However it returns nothing whereas it should. I think the matter is the reading of the 4th number of line 1 which is the date (in my example 18088.90328565). This field is probably not read the correct way.

Comment: What are the values of `$firstTime` and `$lastTime`?

Comment: $firstTime = 1999350 and $lastTime = 2000025

Comment: How are those supposed to be compared with a date like `18088.90328565`?

Comment: What date does that represent?

Comment: Ok i think i know why it's not working : the4th number of line 1 should not be used like this it should be pre-treated by a function i'm using. I guess in your example $4 stands for this date and it should be pre-treated by my function formatDate(). So can I replace $4 by  formatDate($4) ?

Comment: formatDate($4) did not work but $(formatDate $4) worked. However the script returns nothing whereas it should. How do the code know that $4 refers to my fourth number ? Can it be caused by the fact that there are several spaces between the third field and the fourth one ?

Comment: Is `formatDate` an `awk` function or a shell function?

Comment: @Clem That's how `awk` works. `$1` is the first field, `$2` is the second field, and so on.

Comment: Are field separated by one single space ? In my case there are several spaces between the third field and the fourth field

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72935/using-bash-shell-function-inside-awk for calling a shell command from `awk`.

Comment: The default field separator is any amount of whitespace. It sounds like you need to read an `awk` tutorial, you're not going to learn the whole language by asking me.

Comment: Maybe you should talk to your colleague.

Comment: anyway thank you for your help, I feel the solution is not so far away now :)

Comment: The date format is looks like: year:`18` day:`088` (yesterday) `.` some duration (if ms, the time between these records is ~15 hours) or some code?

Comment: You can define functions in `awk`, so it should be pretty easy to create an `awk` version of `formatDate`.

Comment: your guess about the date format is right, the digit after the "." represents the fraction of the day (starting at midnight)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based upon my original but taking into account some new information that *@clem* sent us in comment -- to the effect that we now know that the line we need to test is always immediately subsequent to the line matching `/^@/`.  Therefore, when we match in this new solution, we immediately do a `getline` to grab the next line, and set `ok` based upon that next line's data.  We now  only check against limits on the line subsequent to our match, and we do not check against limits on lines where we shouldn't.

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v ll="$firstTime" -v ul="$lastTime" '
    BEGIN { ok = 0 }
    /^@/  {
        getline
        ok = (ll == "" || ll <= $4) && (ul == "" || $4 <= ul)
    }
    ok # <- print if ok
' "$file"
```